# How to drag drop two events on fullcalendar.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, drag-and-drop, fullcalendar

I am using fullcalendar.js (http://fullcalendar.io/) with jquery ui selectable.

I am able to drag and drop single events, but I am trying to select multiple events and drag-n-drop them together. The following code allows me to select multiple events:

```
 $("div.fc-view").selectable({  
       appendTo:"body",
       filter: "div.fc-event",
       distance:1
  });
```

Is there any way to drag all (e.g. weeks) events together, and drop them on next week?

Answer (score 1):

I have faced similar requirement and also spent lot of time to achieve this but at some point while moving to next week create problems.
So I just you to use context menu  on event right click where you can put copy and move button. Then move to next week and again context menu on select where paste button will appear. Thus you can make copy,move and paste feature easily.

Comment: Thanks, that's a nice suggestion.